# (Unexpected SQL_NO_TOTAL) error on text fields larger than 4096 bytes

Tags: haskell, freetds, hdbc

I filed a bug report: https://github.com/hdbc/hdbc-odbc/issues/4

But maybe this is not the hdbc-odbc issue, so i'll ask here as well.

OS: linux 64 bit (archlinux), ghc-7.4.1, hdbc-odbc-2.3.1.0

Connecting to MS Sql server 2005.

Retrieving a text field larger than 4096 bytes.

With unixodbc 2.3.0 and freetds 0.82 works fine

With unixodbc 2.3.1 and freetds 0.91 gives an error "Unexpected SQL_NO_TOTAL"

tsql utility retrieves and shows large text field fine on freetds 0.91.

Anyone had problems with latest freetds, large text fields and MS SQL server ?

EDIT: I added correct handling of large text fields into hdbc-odbc. The patch is here: 
https://github.com/vagifverdi/hdbc-odbc/commit/8134f715c18a0d60cc7b0329c7c2dbfee3e3e932

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added correct handling of large text fields into hdbc-odbc. The patch is here: https://github.com/vagifverdi/hdbc-odbc/commit/8134f715c18a0d60cc7b0329c7c2dbfee3e3e932

It is included in the latest hdbc-odbc on hackage.